# Prevent use of Contract Functions - Non Verified Non Published

Tags: security

I have run into a problem and don't know the best practice for this.
I am developing a game with Unity and using it to communicate with my EVM contracts.

eg. backend gives a variable gold = 100 from the game database, and it is passed to my contracts mint function so that 100 gold is added to the users wallet as a token.

The problem is people can decompile the code on etherscan.com and easily create and play around with the ABI to hack my contract as the mint function is public. Even though i am not going to publish or verify the code, is there any way around this? how are the other games doing it right now? I saw one contract using manager role but still the transfer will need to be handled by a person, how can it be automated and secured?

all advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your backend can have privileged access to your mint function. Look into OpenZeppelin's [access contracts](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/tree/master/contracts/access) to figure out how best to add permissions to your functions.

Or you could try writing something on your own like so (pseudo-code):

```
address backendAddress;
function permissionedMint() external {
    require(msg.sender == backendAddress);
    _safeMint()...
}
```

The other thing that you have to think about is centralization. If you have some manager that controls what's added or minted on-chain, then it is my belief that it defeats the purpose of decentralization. Your centralized manager backend is essentially the same as a backend on a normal game, but with a more expensive database.

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, i do understand, but decentralization is not the key part of this game. My problem is even if i use the manager role to mint in backend, how will i get the tokens to the end-user? they will still be minted by the manager role and will be in the manager's wallet.

Comment: You can mint directly into a specific wallet, it doesn't have to be to the manager's wallet. Take OpenZeppelin's implementation for example. You can use _safeMint to specify which address to mint to.

function _safeMint(
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId,
        bytes memory _data
    )